# PHP: Readfile works at localhost but not at server

Tags: php, xampp, readfile

I tried to solve my problems for hours and searched google and several boards, but i haven't found a solution.

My Problem: I built a PHP-script what generates a download.
Code below:

```
$file = "file.pdf";
$download_folder = "../contents/"; //RELATIV
$type= mime_content_type($download_folder.$file);
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");

    readfile($download_folder.$file);
```

If I try it at my localhost server (xampp) it works and the download of the file begins. If I upload the script to my hosting server (not an own, it's goneo) i only get a blank page.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check for the permission. 
If you have read permission on the file. 
you can use chmod command to set permission.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got error reporting turned on and are displaying everything during development:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

That should tell you what the problem is.

My guess is that it's having an issue with the path.
Try using an absolute path such as `/var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/httpdocs/contents/file.pdf`.

If that fails, then its probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Good idea! The mime type function doesn't exist at the server. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
if (!file_exists($download_folder . $file)) {
   die("can't find the file")
}
if (!is_readable($download_folder . $file)) {
   die("can't read the file")
}
```

before doing the `header()` calls. Most likely you've uploaded the filesomewhere other than where this script expects it to be, or isn't readable by the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. At the webserver wasn't the function mime_content_type .Thanks for your help